# Door not hitting frame evenly

Tags: doors, hinges, latches

My door latch is not catching but I realized that the door is hitting the frame unevenly. The door seems to hit the frame first at top - I have to pull the door in with a bit of force to make it catch.

Can I adjust the hinges?

I don't just want to adjust the strike plate because there will still be gaps where the door hits the frame.

[image]

Comment: Will need to see/find which part is not plumb.  Is it the door, the door frame, or the door stop.  The door stop is the easiest to fix if the problem.  The hinges will need moving enough so the screws go into good wood away from the old holes.  The frame is the hardest mainly because of the finish/paint.

Comment: What you adjust depends on what's actually wrong with it. You need to figure out whether the door's warped, whether the frame has moved or if it was just badly hung.

Answer (score 1):

You need to analyse *which* part is out of true, to decide the best remedial action.

If the frame has moved, shift the hinges. Out at the top, in at the bottom.
This is fiddly, but needs no redecoration.

If the door is warped, chamfer out the door stop at the top.

If you only adjust the striker, the door will rattle in the frame.

Here's an extreme case.
<sub>Click for full size</sub>
[image]

Frame is moving [subsidence over 120 years] but also the door is warping [sh*t happens].

Right now, this has a part-fix. The bottom of the door gets planed off at the right as the hinges at the left drop [almost in parallel, fortunately]. The hinges have been moved to allow the catch to reach properly, because over time the door catch drops in relation to the strike in the frame - but because of the door warping as well, the top of the stop has been chamfered out to let the top of the door close further.
If the door wasn't warped, moving the hinges would have been enough - and, because this is so extreme, planing the bottom right of the door [hence the visible gap at the top right which can't be fixed without rebuilding the entire door frame].

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix what you ask is the reset the jamb to match the plane of the door. Adjusting the hinges as you ask would simply move the objectionable gap to another place within the opening.

I was reminded of another way, by adjusting the door stop at the top. With the coats of paint that is on the door, you will need to run a razor knife where the stop meets the jamb so when the stop is moved it will not chip the paint. There is still a chance the paint will chip, but this will lessen it. After that a block of wood about a foot long and a hammer to tap the stop over a bit to help the door meet the latch better, and set new nails to keep it there.

Or you could file the strike. The amount you would need to file the strike would be minimal to get the door to latch much more readily. I would recommend doing that, as opposed to moving the strike out the 1/16" to fix the problem. Besides, moving the strike out will create even more issues.

Comment: Your first paragraph depends on whether the door itself is straight or not. Only if the door is warped will moving the jamb be the only useful option. I live in a house full of moving & warping bits of 120-year-old wood. There are many way to skin a cat.

Comment: Could adjust the stop, could adjust the door hinges, could adjust the striker if all you care about is not needing to pull it to latch.

Comment: Good answer. (And I agree with you that warped doors generally stay warped.)